# How to prove that $\mathbb N^4$ bij $\mathbb N$?

Tags: infinite-product

**bij means bijection**. If a set bij the natural numbers set,then the set is countably infinite

For $\mathbb{N}^2$ bij $\mathbb N$,we could assume that is a $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ matrix such as:
\begin{pmatrix}
(1,1)&(1,2)&(1,3)&\cdots&(1,N)\\
(2,1)&(2,2)&(2,3)&\cdots&(2,N)\\
&&\vdots\\
(N,1)&(N,2)&(N,3)&\cdots&(N,N)
\end{pmatrix}
and we could easily prove that for a random $(m,n)$,it will correspond to a nature number which is $\frac{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)}{2}+m$. Thus we could prove $\mathbb N^2$ bij $\mathbb N$.But how about $\mathbb N^4$? This is four-dimensional and I don't think I could still use the above way to prove $\mathbb N^4$ bij $\mathbb N$. So is there any other way to prove this?

Comment: bij${}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: I mean bijection.If a set bij N,then the set is countably infinite.

Comment: So then, what is $N$?

Comment: It must be natural numbers set

Comment: So you are looking at pairs such as $(1,N)$ where $1$ denotes the number $1$ and $N$ is the set of natural numbers?

Comment: No，I am prepared to prove that N^4 is a countably infinite set.And in order to prove that,I need to prove that each number in the N^4 set will correspond to a natural number.In the book it is called bij.

Comment: You say no, but you did write "$(1,N)$" (more strictly speaking "(1,N)").

Comment: I mean the line has N elements and the column also has N elements.So there is totally N^2 elements in the matrix(each element is a coordinate).And for any  random (m,n) in this matrix,the (m,n) will correspond to a nature number because this natural number can be computed through (m+n-1)(m+n-2)/2+m.So we could say **the set N^2 bij the natural numbers set** since each element of the set will correspond to a natural number.Thus,N*N bij N.But how about N^4?What I am confused is how to prove N^4 bij N instead of N^2 bij N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a bijection $\ b_2:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\ $ then
$$
b_4(i,j,k,l) \overset{\text{Def}}{=} b_2 (b_2(i,j),b_2(k,l))
$$
defines a bijection $\ b_4:\mathbb{N}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\ $.

**Proof:** First suppose that $
b_4\left(i_1,j_1,k_1,l_1\right)=b_4 \left(i_2,j_2,k_2,l_2\right)\ $. Then, by definition,
\begin{align}
b_2\left(b_2\left(i_1,j_1\right),b_2 \left(k_1,l_1\right) \right)&=b_4\left(i_1,j_1,k_1,l_1\right)\\
&=b_4\left( i_2,j_2,k_2,l_2 \right)\\
&= b_2\left(b_2 \left(i_2,j_2 \right),b_2\left(k_2,l_2\right)\right)\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ b_2\left(i_1,j_1\right)= b_2 \left(i_2,j_2 \right)\ $ and $\ b_2 \left(k_1,l_1\right)=b_2\left(k_2,l_2\right)\ $, because $\ b_2\ $ is a bijection, and then, that $\ i_1=i_2, j_1=j_2, k_1=k_2\ $ and $\ l_1=l_2\ $, for the same reason. Thus $\ b_4\ $ is injective.

Now suppose that $\ n\ $ is any natural number. Then since $\ b_2\ $ is a bijection, there must exist natural numbers $\ n_1, n_2\ $ such that $\ n= b_2\left(n_1,n_2\right)\ $. For the same reason, there must exist natural numbers $\ i,j,k\ $ and $\ l\ $ such that $\ n_1= b_2\left(i,j\right)\ $ and $\ n_2= b_2\left(k,l\right)\ $. We then have
\begin{align}
n&= b_2\left(n_1,n_2\right)\\
&= b_2 (b_2(i,j),b_2(k,l))\\
&= b_4(i,j,k,l)\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ b_4\ $ is surjective. Since $\ b_4\ $ is both injective and surjective, it is a bijection.

Comment: But it seems that we need double counts of nature numbers?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.  Are you contesting the assertion that $\ b_4\ $ as I've defined it is a bijection?

Comment: Yes,still feel confused

Comment: Since I can't understand the nature of your confusion, I'm not sure whether a proof of bijectivity is going to be of any help, but, in any case, I've added one to my answer.

Comment: Thanks,I will check it

Comment: Another qusetion,does we define the `b4(i,j,k,l)=b2(b2(i,j),b2(k,l))` at first? It is a conclusion we can then use in the proof,right?

Comment: It's a definition which assumes $\ b_2\ $ has already been defined, and is itself a bijection.  For concreteness, you could take $\ b_2\ $ to be the bijection you've already given in your question:
$$
b_2(i,j)\overset{\text{Def}}{=}\frac{(i+j-1)(i+j-2)}{2}+j\ .
$$

Comment: ok,I have figured it out